# Responsive Image Gallery with a content hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After 3 days of trying to figure something out I have come to you, the good people of stackoverflow.

I have managed to create a quite nice looking responsive, masonry type gallery on my website, that I found on CodePen, here - http://codepen.io/justinklemm/pen/iCelj

Heres how it looks on my site - dangoodeofficial.co.uk/290-2

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_loumsfBCuE1qeo682o1_500.jpg">
<img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m1yru9PNMV1qeo682o1_500.jpg">
<img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m24ic6kY6Q1qeo682o1_500.jpg">
<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lriz0lDN2y1qeo682o1_500.jpg">
<img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lrmgjaL62O1qeo682o1_500.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
} 

.gallery img {
float: left;
padding: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function scaleGallery()
{
// This is roughly the max pixels width/height of a square photo
var widthSetting = 400;

// Do not edit any of this unless you know what you're doing
var containerWidth = $(".gallery").width();
var ratioSumMax = containerWidth / widthSetting;
var imgs = $(".gallery img");
var numPhotos = imgs.length, ratioSum, ratio, photo, row, rowPadding, i = 0;

while (i < numPhotos) {
ratioSum = rowPadding = 0;
row = new Array();
while (i < numPhotos && ratioSum < ratioSumMax) {
    photo = $(imgs[i]);
    // reset width to original
    photo.width(""); 
    ratio = photo.width() / photo.height();
    rowPadding += getHorizontalPadding(photo);
    // if this is going to be first in the row, clear: left
    if(ratioSum == 0) photo.css("clear", "left"); else photo.css("clear",         "none");
    ratioSum += ratio;
    row.push(photo);
    i++;
    // if only 1 image left, squeeze it in
    if(i == numPhotos - 1) ratioSumMax = 999;
}
unitWidth = (containerWidth - rowPadding) / ratioSum;

row.forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.width(unitWidth * elem.width() / elem.height());
});
}
}

function getHorizontalPadding(elem)
{
var padding = 0;
var left = elem.css("padding-left");
var right = elem.css("padding-right");
padding += parseInt(left ? left.replace("px", "") : 0);
padding += parseInt(right ? right.replace("px", "") : 0);
return padding;
}

$(window).load(scaleGallery);
$(window).resize(scaleGallery);
```

What I am trying to achieve now is something very similar to this - http://thesaxman.com/#gallery

I am not great at HTML/CSS, so I am not sure where to start, as I have tried taking examples from many different hover effect tutorials but I can not get anything to work.

Any help is going to be most highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: The example you supplied uses divs with absolutely positioned children as overlays. Retrofitting to your site would be an extremely labor intensive process since your's is based on image and not divs wrapping images

Comment: @Paulie_D Is there no way to create something similar the way I have it set up? Would I need to re-evaluate how I have created my gallery in that case and start again?

Comment: Not without a great deal of JS I suspect.

Comment: @Paulie Thanks Paulie, back to the drawing board I guess. All part of the learning curve :-). I don't suppose you could point me in the right direction of how to create absolute positioned divs with child overlays for this purpose?